# How to split a dictionary into a 9x9 2D array, consisting only of the dictionary values

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

If I have a dictionary, say

```
test_dict
```

and it contains 81 entries, in the current correct order.

How would I convert the dictionary's 81 values only into a 9x9 2D array? First 9 values make up the first 9 item array, second 9 values make up the second, and so on. Is it possible with numpy? I feel as though I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.
Here I have taken a dictionary having 4 elements.
Extracted values from dictionary to a numpy array, then reshaped it to 2X2. You can reshape it to 9 by 9

```
import numpy as np

values = {1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 2, 4 : 5}

vals = np.fromiter(values.values(), dtype=int)
print(vals.reshape(2,2))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2]
 [2 5]]
```